# ERR CF on Canon Rebel XT

Tags: canon, dslr, troubleshooting, digital

welcome back to 2008. I just picked up a Rebel XT for super cheap and I've been messing with it for the last couple days trying to trouble shoot (knowing very little about DSLR cameras) and I can't see any bent pins, I've tried another CF card and it doesn't work with the two I have.
Has there been an answer to this to this, what seems to have been very popular, problem with this camera?

Option 1: Buy a SD to CF card adaptor for the hope that it uses less of the connector pins (?) and works, giving me the option to have more storage anyways.

Option 2: send it out to get fixed up, which is probably not worth the money.

Option 3: just get rid of it and buy a new camera body.

preferably would just like to make this work and keep it just to have something to mess with in my free time, since I got it for like $40.

Comment: What size CF cards do you have? I'd expect the camera to work with cards larger than what it supports, but it might not be able to format them, or might not work at all. Try a card like 1GB or 4GB.

Comment: To absolutely rule out the card, double check the firmware to make sure it's updated, and go get your hands on a small card as @Caleb suggests. Old cameras struggle with new, larger cards. If the smaller card works, you can usually use it to update your firmware, which *may* allow use of larger cards.

Answer (score 1):

2008? More like the beginning of 2005. The EOS Rebel XT/350D replacement was the Rebel XTi/400D, introduced in mid-2006. The XTi/400D was replaced by the EOS Rebel XS/450D in early 2008.

I suspect your issue is that the cards aren't preformatted properly for the camera's file system *and* they are either too large for the camera to format them itself *or* they are formatted using a file system other than the needed FAT32. Most memory card makers at the time (SanDisk, Kingston, etc.) recommended cards no larger than 8GB for the 350D.

If you are trying to use CF cards larger than 8GB, you'll need to format them in a computer and create the needed file structure for the camera's operating system. If the CF card is already formatted using a file system other than FAT32 you'll need to use a computer to reformat the card using FAT32.

Instead of formatting in the camera, use your PC. As long as you use the correct file system (FAT32) and set up the needed folder structure after you format the card via the PC there should be no issues using the card. The reason almost everyone says to format in-camera is because that is the most user friendly way to guarantee the correct file system and folder structure.

- Be sure that the FAT32 file system is selected when the card is formatted.
- Label the card 'EOS_DIGITAL'.
- Manually create a folder in the root of the card named 'DCIM'.
- Then insert the card into your Rebel XT/300D and see if it is recognized.

More recent Canon cameras include instructions in the User Manual for how to properly format and set up the needed file structure using a PC.

[image]

Page 135 of the [*EOS 6D Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300009238/01/eos6d-im-en.pdf) explains how to create the needed folder structure and how to name folders. All folders with images must be created inside a folder named "DCIM". Basically each folder name must have 8 digits consisting of three numerical digits from 100 to 999 and five alphabetic (or _) digits. There can only be one folder that begins with any unique 3 digit number between 100 and 999, regardless of the five alphabetic characters that follow. You can have both a folder "100AAAAA" and "101AAAAA", but not both a folder "100AAAAA" and "100AAAAB".

One easy way to do this after the first time would be to erase all images on the card (which would leave the folder structure intact), copy the card's disc image to your computer, format the card on the computer, then copy the disk image back onto the card.

Answer (score 0):

I presume the CF cards you used are known good cards?

If you don't need the data on the CF card, could you format it on the camera?

If not, and it's not physical pin damage, it's doubtful if you could fix it cheaply.

Comment: The cards I've tried aren't new but they aren't damaged in anyway.. from what I can see. When I format them to the camera the loading bar makes it about 30% loading and then says "ERR 99" which I've read usually means there is a problem between the lens and the body and shutters. But it still allows me to "shoot without cf card" and it takes the photo no problem.

Comment: Do you have another camera that takes CF cards where you can validate the card and then move it directly into the XT?